# Using systemd-cgls and cgroups as a user configured pstree

Tags: linux, ps

When using `pstree` I was annoyed that processes forget their grandparent process when they get orphaned since they get adopted by `init`, so I thought maybe I could use `systemd-cgls` and cgroups, since an orphaned process will stay in the cgroup it was created it.  However, after creating a new controller path  and using `cgclassify` to move a process there, the path doesn't show up in `systemd-cgls`, and `cat /proc/[PID]/cgroups` still shows the same `2:name=systemd:/user/1000.user/2.session` rather than the path that I want showing up.  Is there some way get it to do what I want?